# Equation for "importance" value of twitter user according to #followers #following

Tags: algorithm, math, sorting, ranking

I am trying to find an equation which calculates the "importance" of a twitter user according to #following #followers

Things I want to consider:
1. The more #followers / #following is bigger, the more important he his.
2. differ between 20/20 and 10k/10k (10k is more important although the ratio is the same).

Considering these two, I expect to get a similar output importance value to these two inputs:
 #followers=1000 #following=100
 #followers=30k #following=30k

I'm having problems inserting the second point into consideration. I believe it needs to be quite simple. Help?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one possibility is `(#followers/#following)*[log(#followers) - CONST]` where CONST is some predefined value, tested as appropriate. this will ensure the ratio has its appropriate importance, but also the scale matters.

for your last example, you will need to set CONST~=9.4 to achieve similar results.

Comment: @amit Thanks! Can you elaborate a little on why I should use log instead of ^2? Just so it will be clearer in my mind when I do stuff like this in the future...

Comment: @Noam: it seems to me that as higher the #followers is, it should increase, however, it should increase slower... this can be achieved using log(n), while n^2 will make the value increase sharper as #followers increase...

Comment: @amit I get that now. I'm having problems understanding the "/ CONST". Are you suggesting I just divide the answer by a pre-defined number? I can't see how that will change anything. What am I missing?

Comment: @Noam: no that was a mistake, what I actually meant was `(#followers/#following)*log(#followers/CONST)`  = `(#followers/#following)*[log(#followers)  - log(CONST) ]` = `(#followers/#following)*[log(#followers)  - OTHER_CONST ]` . now you can find a CONST/OTHER_CONST which will make the last rule (1000,100 ~= 30k,30) true. (I editted the answer)

Comment: one more thing: It's a bit different then what you have asked, but you might want to consider an alternative: there is a well known Information Retrieval algorithm for ranking: `Hubs and Authorities`. you might want to consider it: if someone is following a lot of people, he might be considered as a hub, if a lot of people follow him, he might be considered as an authority. (reading material in next comment)

Comment: some reading material: http://webcourse.cs.technion.ac.il/236621/Winter2010-2011/ho/WCFiles/lec7-linkAnalysisIntro.pdf (slides 8-12)
and wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HITS_algorithm

Comment: It's really funny that you sent me a link to a course I did, also with Ronny :)

Comment: he's a great lecturer :) anyway, maybe HITS is more appropriate here then the ratio followers/following, one should not 'suffer' if he's following other users. I think if he's following many 'important' users, he's a good hub, and if many good hubs follow him, he's a good authority. I think this approach worth investigating.

Answer (score 1):

There are too many answers to this question, you need to weight how important is the number of followers compared to the ratio so you get a common number to relationate this two. For example the first idea that come to my mind is to multiply the ratio by the log of the #Followers. Something like this.

```
Importance = (#Followers / #Following)*Log(#Followers)
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said there, you could do 3*followers^2/following.

But you've described a system where users can increase their importance by following fewer other users. Doesn't seem too awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You could normalize it by the total number of users.
I'd suggest using logarithms on all the values to get a less dramatic increase or change in higher values.

```
(log(#followers)/log(#TotalNumberOfPeopleInTwitter))*(log(#followers)/log(#following))
```

Comment: Timmer I will use your tip regarding the logs. Can you elaborate more on the normalization?  Maybe give a simple example on what this normalization will acheive?